# vertical-align in div with height 100%

Tags: html, css

Here's my situation: I'm trying to make a page with two DIVsfilling whole page (height 100%, width 50% each). Also, the content in the DIVs is to be vertically aligned to middle.

Is there an easy way to achieve this without hacks or javascript?

I've tried `body,html{height:100%;} .mydiv {display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align-middle}`

but that doesn't work...and with that code, i have to specify width in pixels instead of percentage

Comment: So many questions here answering this topic, please search.

Comment: Not exactly. Some answers are about making the div 100% in height and some are about vertical aligning.
making them co-exist is what i want to do

Comment: Height in CSS (with the exception of a finite object with fixed dimensions) is a nightmare!  I have tried countless times to accomplish this, and just when I think I have it... The solutions breaks something else.  If there is any way to avoid this scenario, I would suggest doing so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YeH84/1/)

I just made [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YeH84/1/) showing my suggestion to a solution. Here I take into account that you want two `<div>`s filling 50% of the width each, 100% height, and that you want the content to be vertically aligned in the middle. Here is the [simplified working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/YeH84/18/) with source code.

### HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="table-container">
        <div id="table-cell">
            This content is vertically centered.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#outer {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

#table-container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

#table-cell {
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

For reference, I used [this tutorial](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Will give you a box that fills to 100% height. Make sure your HTML and BODY tags are large enough:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But that leaves the question half-answered. What about vertical-alignment issue?
With your code, the content is not vertically aligned even with `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this type of design ? => [**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6JJJ8/)